# Turn off read-only pen drive

Tags: usb, format, read-only

I'm trying to format a 64gb pen drive that turned readonly after failing to move a larger video file using gparted but it keeps failing due to the pen drive being in readonly. (just installed Ubuntu for this). Doing `sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb` returns:

```
setting readonly to 0 (off)
readonly     = 1 (on)
```

Is there any other way to turn off readonly? I also tried a bunch of other hdparm commands but they usually return: "no such file or directory"

Comment: `sudo umount /dev/sdb` before you try to format it.

Comment: It looks like your pendrive's hardware is damaged, but you can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's read only because it's dead.

Commonly flash memory devices fails to read only to ensure you can at least get data back. This is corroborated by the fact that it happened during copying files.

Copy what you need from it. Then get a new one. You can check with the vendor if they offer a warranty replacement.